# Switching my git bash credentials from virtual machine to my home system

Tags: bash, git, github

I am about to finish a coding boot camp which had us blindly set up our git and github account info through Vagrant/putty in the beginning using SSH keys. I went ahead and downloaded cmder and set it up to launch bash on terminal open, but when I try to git push or pull, I am getting an error Permission denied(publickey). fatal: could not read from remote repository.

I have checked the username and email, and they are set to my correct credentials. Will the fact that I made the SSH keys while logged in to the schools Vagrant system cause issues, and if so, is there a way to strip and reset my SSH keys or switch my git to use HTTPS credentials to log in?

I've done a good bit of googling and only come across ways to install and setup git bash, which I've of course already done. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One benefit of using SSH keys over your username and password is that you can *have* separate keys for each machine you'll log into GitHub with. Don't transfer the keys; just generate new ones for your home machine, and disable the old VM keys on GitHub's end.

Comment: Would you suggest this over the HTTPS option I've seen in my research? It's listed as the recommended option on git's site, but I don't quite understand why.

Comment: @JoshBangle: There's one big advantage to https: sometimes, everything else is blocked. If ssh *isn't* blocked, then at least to me, it seems superior all around for this kind of authentication.

Comment: @torek thanks for the info, I'll stick with SSH then since it's my local machine and that shouldn't be an issue.